# IIS Express Hangs with Curl Request

Tags: php, curl, iis-express

I am developing a website with php 5.4 using Visual Studio 2013, Xdebug, and IIS Express. Whenever I attempt a curl request to localhost:port, the page hangs until the the curl request fails due to timeout. However, after the curl timeout occurs, the rest of the code on the requesting page executes, and then the code on the requested page executes, which does not help me as I need the data from the page.

Here is the script that makes the curl request:

```
    $logfh = fopen("C:\Windows\Temp\curl_log.log", 'a+');
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://localhost:46746/test.php');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "XDEBUG_SESSION=" . $_COOKIE['XDEBUG_SESSION'] . ';');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,5);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE , true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_STDERR ,$logfh );
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($logfh);
```

Here is the script on the requested page:

```
  <?php
    echo 'reached test';
    ?>
```

Here is the log of the curl request:

```
Adding handle: conn: 0x370ea80
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 3 (0x370ea80) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to localhost port 46746 (#3)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 46746 (#3)

> GET /test.php HTTP/1.1 Host: localhost:46746 Accept: */* Cookie: XDEBUG_SESSION=A53CF524;

Operation timed out after 5991 milliseconds with 0 out of -1 bytes received
* Closing connection 3
```

My curl syntax should be correct, since I can successfully get data from another url. PHP does not show any errors. What should I be doing differently?

Comment: Why are you using port 46746? Normally you listen on 80

Comment: @Machavity - that is the port IIS Express chose to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer turned out to be simple.I went into Project Properties and selected the server setting 'Use Local IIS Express'. I had Visual Studio create the virtual directory for me, and it works just fine now.

Answer (score 1):

These two options are true/false:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE , $logfh );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $logfh);
```

**UPDATE**

There are a few things you can do to assist in finding the problem

The `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` and `CURLOPT_FAILONERROR`
are important when debugging.
 
Without the timeout it will not timeout and you will not see any results.

I like to see if the server responded at all and the HTTP Response Header may have relevant information, so use `CURLOPT_HEADER`

Use `curl_getinfo($ch);` to get the results.

Check curl response for errors: `curl_errno($ch))`

`CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT` will return your Request Header which may reveal a problem with your request e.g cookies.

Set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to false in case you have a recursive redirect.

If you do not need cookies, don't use them, remove them while debugging.

This header is so no echoed output is interpreted as HTML.

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "TestCookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "TestCookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$info = var_export($info,true);
  if (curl_errno($ch)){
      $data .= 'Retreive Base Page Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
  }
  else {
    $skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
    $responseHeader = substr($data,0,$skip);
    $data= substr($data,$skip);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $info = var_export($info,true);
   }
  echo $responseHeader;
  echo "\n$info";
  echo "\n$data";
```

You may need to alter the default header.

```
$request = array();
$request[] = "Host: www.example.com";
$request[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
$request[] = "User-Agent: MOT-V9mm/00.62 UP.Browser/6.2.3.4.c.1.123 (GUI) MMP/2.0";
$request[] = "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5";
$request[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$request[] = "Cache-Control: no-cache";
$request[] = "Pragma: no-cache";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$request);
```

If you need a POST request:

```
$post = 'key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
```

The curl cookie jar is sometimes problematic.  so I wrote may own cookie routine.

Get cookies from the Response Header:

```
  $e = 0;
  while(true){
    $s = strpos($head,'Set-Cookie: ',$e);
    if (!$s){break;}
    $s += 12;
    $e = strpos($head,';',$s);
    $cookie = substr($head,$s,$e-$s) ;
    $s = strpos($cookie,'=');
    $key = substr($cookie,0,$s);
    $value = substr($cookie,$s);
    $cookies[$key] = $value;
  }
```

Create the cookies for any subsequent requests:

```
 $cookie = '';
 $show = '';
 $head = '';
 $delim = '';
 foreach ($cookies as $k => $v){
   $cookie .= "$delim$k$v";
   $delim = '; ';
 }
```

Add the cookies to the request header:

```
$request = array();  // clear requests from previous request.
$request[] = $cookies;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$request);
```

Comment: I changed CURLOPT_VERBOSE to 'true' and removed the CURLOPT_FILE line.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the detailed response. However, my problem was not with curl, but with my project setup (see my answer).

Comment: Yes, I think you posted your answer as I was working on the update.  I was thinking you had a connection that would not time out because you had no `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT`.